# Java: Split string and store in ArrayList based on value

Tags: java, string, arraylist, version

I have an ArrayList of strings. These strings are structured as follows:

xxxx_Contract_2.1.0.xlsx

The last digits refer to the version. So I am trying to get the latest version for each contract to put all the strings containing the last version of their contract in list A, while all other strings from older versions of the same contract are listed in list B.

I had different solutions in my mind, but they always seemed to be dirty workarounds that could break if my supervisor changed the structure. Does anyone have an idea, how to get the string of a particular contract that's the latest version of that contract?

Comment: Since computers aren't humans, there has to be some sort of pattern your supervisor needs to follow for this to work. Something as simple as keeping the versions on the end of the file and the name of the contract at the start? You could try predict what he may use or change to in the future.

Comment: tell your supervisor to stay with the current, working, name standard

Comment: The position of the name and its version will always stay the same. What I meant with structure change is: He might add other excel-files / folders etc. to his structure. My filecrawler will retrieve all excel files and put them into an ArrayList. So in worst case, my program will crash because of incompatible Strings, like different files than .xlsx or .xlsx files with other names, since they are needed for other tasks. There is also no way to predict the changes, since I have to access an interface which is managed by another department in order to retrieve those excel files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a scheme major.minor.bug for the file version. You need to parse out these values and then make them comparable.

Here's an implementation.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
        files.add("xxxx_Contract_2.1.0.xlsx");
        files.add("xxxx_Contract_2.2.0.xlsx");
        files.add("xxxx_Contract_2.1.3.xlsx");
        files.add("xxxx_Contract_4.6.3.xlsx");
        files.add("xxxx_Contract_4.6.2.xlsx");

        Version latest = null;
        for (String file : files) {
            if (latest == null) {
                latest = new Version(file);
                continue;
            }
            Version v = new Version(file);
            if (latest.compareTo(v) < 0) {
                latest = v;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Latest version " + latest.filename);
    }

    static class Version implements Comparable<Version> {
        private static final String VERSION_REGEX = ".*(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+).*";
        private static final Pattern REGEX;
        static {
            REGEX = Pattern.compile(VERSION_REGEX);
        }

        private String filename;
        private Integer major;
        private Integer minor;
        private Integer bug;

        public Version(String filename) throws Exception {
            Matcher m = REGEX.matcher(filename);
            if (!m.matches()) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid filename " + filename);
            }

            this.filename = filename;
            this.major = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
            this.minor = Integer.valueOf(m.group(2));
            this.bug =  Integer.valueOf(m.group(3));
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Scratch.Version o) {
            int result = major.compareTo(o.major);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
            result = minor.compareTo(o.minor);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
            result = bug.compareTo(o.bug);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
Latest version xxxx_Contract_4.6.3.xlsx

Comment: Thank you, I think, I will use you solution with some modifications and a hashmap. This might work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as version follows following structure which likely it is in general,

MajorVersion.MinorVersion.BugFixVersion

e.g. 2.1.0

You can use following regex to extract it from filename string no matter what your supervisor changes the filename structure too

```
\\d+[.]\\d+[.]\\d+
```

For e.g. if filename is changed to xxxx_Contract_2.1.0_abcd.xlsx or xxxx_2.1.0_Contract_.xlsx or 2.1.0_xxxx_Contract.xlsx, the regex will surely extract the version text you are interested in.

Once you find and collect all the versions, say in an ArrayList, write a Comparator to sort these and get the minimum or maximum. Let me know if you have trouble writing Comparator. I can help.

Answer (score 0):

To get the version number out of the file name:

```
String filename = "xxxx_Contract_2.1.0.xlsx";
String version = filename.replaceAll("^.*_Contract_|\\.xlsx$", "");
System.out.println(version);  // "2.1.0"
```

Now you can use a comparator to find the latest contract, but you need to be careful. Comparing version numbers can be a can of worms. There are various existing StackOverflow questions and answers on this topic.

Comment: What does ^.* do?

In case I have a list with a_Contract_1.0.0.xlsx and b_Contract_1.0.0.xlsx. Will I be able to differentiate between them?

Comment: the input is a list of strings like:

a_Contract_1.0.0.xlsx
a_Contract_1.0.3.xlsx
b_Contract_1.0.3.xlsx
c_Contract_1.0.0.xlsx
c_Contract_3.4.1.xlsx
.
.
.

Comment: @dnsiv `^.*` means any number (`*`) of any characters (denoted by `.`) at the start of the string (denoted by `^`). You may need to build a map (e.g. `HashMap`) of contracts where the key is the customer name (the bit before "_Contract_") and the value is a list of version numbers.